# Flask: How do you access group by sum and counts in jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the values for a query:

```
total_sales =  (Model.query
                .with_entities(Model.dept_name,
                               sa.func.sum(Model.sales),
                               sa.func.count(Model.sales))
                .filter(Model.companyid == companyid)
                .filter(Model.sales> 0)
                .group_by(Model.companyid, Model.dept_name)
                .all())
```

In my jinja code I have:

```
{% for item in total_sales %}
             <tr>
                <td>{{ item.dept_name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.sum }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

The dept_name shows up but the `item.sum` isn't showing and the `item.count` shows up as `<built-in method count of result object at 0x000002DEA910D098>`

If I `print(total_sales)` I can see the results of the query as a list of tuples.  How do I access this in my jinja file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add labels to the function results so you can access them more clearly. Since you are using `count` and `sum` in the template, it'd be like:

```
sa.func.sum(Model.sales).label('sum'),
sa.func.count(Model.sales).label('count')
```

Comment: I was able to figure out that I could access sum and count as `item[1]` and `item[2]` respectively.  However, I added the labels in from your example and could access by `item.sum` and `item.count`.  I also did fix the table layout as well (in my code not on stackoverflow).